# Does Kaam only increases by indulging in it?

Tags: sex, kama

Is it true that Kama (sexual and romantic desires towards women) only increases by indulging in it ?
I think Yayati said this in Mahabharata. Apart from him who has said this ?

Answer (score 3):

Vyasa also said something similar.

**Vyasa’s view of Desire**

> Vyasa said, ‘There is a wonderful tree, called Desire, in the heart of
> a man. It is born of the seed called Error. Wrath and pride constitute
> its large trunk. The wish for action is the basin around its foot (for
> holding the water that is to nourish it). Ignorance is the root of
> that tree, and heedlessness is the water that gives it sustenance.
> Envy constitutes its leaves. The evil acts of past lives supply it
> with vigour. Loss of judgment and anxiety are its twigs; grief forms
> its large branches; and fear is its sprout. Thirst (after diverse
> objects) that is (apparently) agreeable forms the creepers that twine
> round it on every side. Excessively greedy men, bound in chains of
> iron, sitting around that fruit-yielding tree, pay their adorations to
> it, in expectation of obtaining its fruit. He who, subduing those
> chains, cutteth down that tree and seeks to cast off both sorrow and
> joy, succeeds in attaining to the end of both. **That foolish man who
> nourishes this tree by indulgence in the objects of the senses is
> destroyed by those very objects in which he indulges after the manner
> of a poisonous pill destroying the patient to whom it is
> administered.** A dexterous person, however, by the aid of Yoga,
> forcibly teareth up and cutteth with the sword of Samadhi, the
> far-reaching root of this tree. One who knows that the end of all acts
> undertaken from only the desire of fruit is rebirth or chains that
> bind, succeeds in transcending all sorrow.’

**Mahabharata, Santi Parva, Section CCLIV**